# Python Forms 400 error multiple requests

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, http-status-code-400

I am utilizing flask/flask-wtf with several forms on one page.  My app.py code statements work with the first two if statements which is part of one form, but fails with 400 error on the 3rd/4th if statements.  If I swap them in the views, they will work.  Also my tabbing seems off on stackoverflow, but it is fine on my ide.

**app.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        ###delete
     delete = request.form["add"] == 'Delete'
     if delete:
        print "here at add elete"
        #One
        selectedOne = request.form.getlist('selectAddressOne')
        any_selected = bool(selectedOne)
        if any_selected is True:

               wallet.autobtcaddress01 = ''
               db.session.add(wallet)
               db.session.commit()
               return redirect(url_for('wallet.walletPageAutoWithdraw', username=user.username))


    Add = request.form["add"] == 'Add'
    if Add:

        selectedOne = request.form.getlist('selectAddressOne')
        any_selected = bool(selectedOne)
        if any_selected is True:
            print "here"
            wallet.autobtcaddress01 = form.addressOne.data
            db.session.add(wallet)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('wallet.walletPageAutoWithdraw', username=user.username))
    abortOn= request.form.getlist["Abort"] == "On"
    if abortOn:
        print "abort on"
        wallet.autostatus = "Active"
        db.session.add(wallet)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('wallet.walletPageAutoWithdraw', username=user.username))

    Abortoff= request.form.getlist["Abort"] == "Abort"
    if Abortoff:
        wallet.autostatus = "Off"
        db.session.add(wallet)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('wallet.walletPageAutoWithdraw', username=user.username))
```

**Html**

```
<div id="TurnonorOff">
    <form method=POST action="">
    <input class="btn btn-default" type=submit value="On" name="Abort">
    <input class="btn btn-danger"  type=submit value="Abort" name="Abort">
    </form>
</div>

 <div id="Form5Checkbox">

         {{ render_field(form.selectAddressFive, prefs='no')}}
    </div>
    <div id="Form5">
         {{ render_field(form.addressFive,value=wallet.btcaddress05,
            autocomplete="off", type="text", size='50') }}


<div id="TurnonorOff">
    <form method=POST action="">
    <input class="btn btn-default" type=submit value="On" name="Abort">
    <input class="btn btn-danger"  type=submit value="Abort" name="Abort">
    </form>
</div>



<div id="WalletAutoButtonList">
<input class="btn btn-primary" type=submit value="Add" name="add">
<input class="btn btn-danger" type=submit value="Delete" name="add">

</div>

</div>
</form>
```

I did leave out some html/python code as I thought it was unnecessarily long and irrelevant code.

Answer (score 0):

After careful comparison I realized this was the issue:

```
  abortOn= request.form.getlist["Abort"] == "On"

  Abortoff= request.form.getlist["Abort"] == "Abort"
```

I changed it to :

```
  abortOn= request.form.get["Abort"] == "On"

  Abortoff= request.form.get["Abort"] == "Abort"
```